# Does this question make sense? - How is German being home for you?

Tags: questions

I met this lady who was born in Asia but said Germany is her home. So I asked:

> "How is Germany being home for you?"

I was curious why Germany is home for her. I think there is something wrong with this sentence and I am struggled.

Comment: German is a language or nationality; Germany is a country. Which do you mean?

Comment: "Why does Germany feel like home to you?"

Comment: "How is Germany home for you?"   would be my choice.  In some regions the word __being__ is more common than others.  In the US, it is less common.

Comment: "How do you like living in Germany?" is probably what most native speakers would say.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of ways to say what I think you mean. The nuances differ.

"Why does Germany feel like home for you?" is a fairly friendly way to ask. (Unsaid is "... when you were born in Asia?"). Or "How does Germany feel like home for you?" might work too.

"How is Germany home for you?" is a potentially aggressive way of asking the same question.

"How do you like living in Germany?" moves away from the person feeling that Germany is their home, but this is probably the most politic and polite way of asking your question.

Comment: How is Germany home for you? is potentially asked by someone who doesn't understand **how Germany could be home for someone**. I upvoted this.